# does it make sense to use greendroid with android 4?

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, greendroid

I'm very new to greendroid and I had a quick look on its functionalities. If I want to develop with the android 4 sdk does it still make sense to use greendroid? Is that gonna work? 
For example let's take the ActionBar. There's one in greendroid but android 4 has now that functionality too so what? Of course it's only one element but is there still an advantage to use greendroid when the base sdk is android 4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

isn't this library intended to support older versions (like 2.x and below) ?
if so (and my guess is that it is ) : if you don't wish to allow such devices to be able to run your app , then you don't need this library .

otherwise , if you wish to have the action bar functionality , you should consider using it (or any other solution for the action bar , like the [action bar sherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) or the android library that google gives.) .

most devices today do not have a new version of android . currently  , most of them run version 2.x .
here's the current statistics:
http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html